# Makefile layer in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, makefile-mode

I've searched all over internet, but couldn't find how can I invoke `make` from spacemacs with a keybinding (not in `shell` window).

All I found was this:
@agriffis on gitter said the following

> Aron Griffis
>   @agriffis
>   Nov 03 2016 22:07
>
> I'm editing a Makefile, and spacemacs reports GNUMakefile as the major mode. That's great, but there's no auto-indentation. I have to tab in every line after hitting enter. Anybody familiar with that?

And then:

> Aron Griffis
>   @agriffis
>   Nov 03 2016 22:35
>
> Hmm, seems like the emacs-provided make-mode.el is just weak. Nobody cares about browser mode or electric keys. It even says in its own todo list:
>
> ;; * Eliminate electric stuff entirely.
>
> ;; * Consider removing browser mode.  It seems useless.
>
> On the other hand, it would be really nice if it did something sensible with indentation, which everybody cares about. sigh.

Does anybody have any updates on this? I use golang and Makefiles are really handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke `make` with [`compile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html).

You can find the updates yourself with `find-library` (<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>Ret</kbd> `make-mode` <kbd>Ret</kbd>). That will automatically find the library and load it into a buffer for you peruse. Also you can follow its development at the [Emacs github mirror](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commits/master/lisp/progmodes/make-mode.el)